# how can I use multiple operation in awk to edit text file

Tags: linux, awk

I have a text file like this small example:

```
chr10:103909786-103910082   147 148 24  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   149 150 11  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   150 151 2   BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   152 153 1   BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   274 275 5   CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   288 289 15  CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   294 295 4   CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   295 296 15  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2925    2926    134 CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2926    2927    10  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2932    2933    2   CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   58  59  1   BA
chr10:104573088-104576021   689 690 12  BA
chr10:104573088-104576021   819 820 33  BA
```

in this file there are 5 `tab separated` columns. the first column is considered as ID. for example in the first row the whole "`chr10:103909786-103910082`" is ID.

`1-` in the 1st step I would like to filter out the rows based on the 4th column. 
if the number in the `4th column is less than 10` and the same row but in the `5th column the group is BA`, that row will be filtered out. also if the number in the `4th column is less than 5` and the same row but in the `5th column the group is CA`, that row will be filtered out.

`3-` 3rd step:
I want to get the ratio of number in `4th column`. in fact in the `1st column` there are repeated values which represent the same `ID`. I want to get one ratio per `ID`, so in the output every `ID` will be repeated only once. each `ID` has both `BA` and `CA` in the `5th column`. for each `ID` I should get 2 values for `CA` and `BA` separately and get the ration of `CA/BA` as the final value for each `ID`. to get one value as `CA`, I should add up all values in the `4th column` which belong the same `ID` and classified as `CA` and to get one value as `BA`, I should add up all values in the `4th column` which belong the same `ID` and classified as `BA`. the last step is to get the ration of `CA/BA` per `ID`. the expected output for the small example would look like this:

`1- after filtration`:

```
chr10:103909786-103910082   147 148 24  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   149 150 11  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   274 275 5   CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   288 289 15  CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   295 296 15  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2925    2926    134 CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2926    2927    10  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   689 690 12  BA
chr10:104573088-104576021   819 820 33  BA
```

`2- after summarizing each group` (`CA` and `BA`):

```
chr10:103909786-103910082   147 148 35  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   274 275 35  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2925    2926    144 CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   819 820 45  BA
```

3- the `final output`(this ratio is made using the values in 4th column):

```
chr10:103909786-103910082   1
chr10:104573088-104576021   3.2
```

in the above lines, 1 = 35/35 and 3.2 = 144/45.

I am trying to do that in `awk`

```
awk -F "\t" '{ (if($4 < -10 & $5==BA)), (if($4 < -5 & $5==CA)) ; print $2 = BA/CA} file.txt > out.txt
```

I tried to follow the steps that mentioned in the code but did not succeed. do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are lines with the same ID always consecutive?

Comment: This question is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852411/combining-different-operations-in-a-text-file-using-awk

Answer (score 1):

If the records with the same ID are always consecutive, you can do that:

```
awk 'ID!=$1 {
         if (ID) {
             print ID, a["CA"]/a["BA"]; a["CA"]=a["BA"]=0;
         }
         ID=$1
     }
     $5=="BA" && $4>=10 || $5=="CA" && $4>=5 { a[$5]+=$4 }
     END{ print ID, a["CA"]/a["BA"] }' file.txt
```

The first block tests if the ID has changed, in this case, it displays the previous ID and the ratio.
The second block filter unwanted records.
The END block displays the result for the last ID.